# Toshiba screen backlight only works occasionally

Tags: brightness, overheating, backlight, toshiba-satellite

I am having a weird problem - I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 and the backlight doesn't work consistently. If I power off my machine and leave it sit for an hour or two, the screen will work fine but if I am using it and I restart my device the screen fails to light up. Once this happens I just restart a bunch of times until the screen lights up again. I am wondering if this is a safety function for the screen getting hot or something and how do I keep it from happening? Any help is appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your /etc/default/grub file like so:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to this instead:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit and then run the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot for the changes to take effect.